# unable to append image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add all gifs in a pop-up window based on user input but I can't get it to work the image is not getting appended to the dialog box its opens but is empty how can I fix this?

regards

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });
  $('#rio').on('click',function () {
    let user_input = prompt();
    const base_url = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?'
    const  key = 'kibe1qE9jIYwWBU0V5YTuNJqYZPEOxOy';
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        $.ajax({
          url:  base_url + 'api_key=' + key + '&q=' + user_input,
          dataType:' text/html',
          }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
              // console.log(data.data[i].embed_url);
              let image = document.createElement('img')
              image.src = data.data[i].embed_url;
              document.getElementById('gifs_div').appendChild(image);
            }
          });
          console.log(user_input);
          console.log('looking up!');
        });
      } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <div class="gifs_div"></div>
    </div>
    <input id="rio" type="button" value="Gifs" title="Gifs"/>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: i dont have any thats the thing

Comment: @j08691, it isn't a bug with the JavaScript, just that he used the wrong tag to display the GIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });
  $('#rio').on('click',function () {
    let user_input = prompt();
    const base_url = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?'
    const  key = 'kibe1qE9jIYwWBU0V5YTuNJqYZPEOxOy';
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        $.ajax({
          method: 'get',
          url:  base_url + 'api_key=' + key + '&q=' + user_input,
          }).done(function(data) {
             // console.log(data)
            for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
              let frame = document.createElement('iframe');
              frame.src = data.data[i].embed_url;
              frame.title = "GIPHY GIF for " + user_input;
              document.body.appendChild(frame);
            }
          });
          console.log(user_input);
          console.log('looking up!');
        });
      } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <div class="gifs_div"></div>
    </div>
    <input id="rio" type="button" value="Gifs" title="Gifs"/>
```

try this here i removed `dataType:' text/html',` from the ajax call, and added  `method: 'get',`, hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before. Is your `<script>` tag above your code? In that block you gave us, it looks like it is above. In JavaScript, code is read from top to bottom, so try moving it to the bottom. If your `<script>` tag was below the code, please edit your question to add a code snippet with the exact code you made.

Edit:

In your code, you used an `<img>` tag, but the GIPHY API outputs an HTML file. Hence, you must use an `<iframe>`. I have edited the for loop in your `done()` function.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    // console.log(data.data[i].embed_url);
    let iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.src = data.data[i].embed_url;
    iframe.title = "GIPHY GIF for " + user_input;
    document.getElementsByClassName('gifs_div')[0].appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: after moving down still empty

Comment: Is your API key 100% valid? You could have missed something.

Comment: After some digging around, I found out that the GIPHY API doesn't send back an image. It sends back an HTML document. I will edit my answer to describe it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to append using document.getElementById but your selector looks like a class name `.gifs_div` rather than `#gifs_div` (this might not be the main issue)